# How to set the grid-template-rows/columns' properties so that if there is not enought element the centering remains?

Tags: html, css

In my case it will be about grid-template-columns, that said I assume the same logic would apply to grid-template-rows.

Here the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rvxhzc?file=style.scss

You will see that the grid's element on right have greater space remaining that the grid's element on left.
This case reproduces a problem I have in my code where a card's layout end with two remaining element instead of three on the other rows. 
I have thought about a property that would set the grid template as "grid-template-columns: repeat(max-repeat(3), auto)", in the same flavor that max-width's allow us to limit the width and still define a width's range meanwhile.

How to ensure that if the final rows has not enough elements to fully fill it, the grid's elements remain centered?

Here the ReactJS' snippet:

```
 <div className="component">
      <p className="component__introducing-text"> if you look attentively you will see the space is different on the two elements' sides</p>
        <div className="component__grid">
          <div className="component__grid-first-element">
            div 1
          </div>
          <div className="component__grid-second-element">
            div 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here the compiled Sass' snippet:

```
.component__grid-second-element, .component__grid-first-element, .component__introducing-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.component__grid-second-element, .component__grid-first-element {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 25vw;
}

.component__introducing-text {
  margin: 10vh auto 0;
}

.component__grid {
  width: calc(100vw - (100vw - 100%));
  margin-top: 8vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-column-gap: 5.5vw;
}

.component__grid-first-element {
  background: pink;
}

.component__grid-second-element {
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: so you will have 1,2 or 3 elements? no more?

Comment: thanks for your answer Temani Afif, it could be more in other instance, so the fundamental idea I am seeking now is how can I ensure that if the final row/column has not enough elements to fulfill the number of repetition inside it, the grid's elements remain centered?

Comment: you need to use Flexbox, CSS grid is not designed to cover this in a generic way. It would be hacky to rely on CSS grid whereas it's pretty easy with flexbox

Comment: effectively there is some property in flexbox that could be interesting here. thanks.